# Unique monotonically increasing ids using Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, distributed-system

I have some kind of time series events that I want to store in a Cassandra database.

The question is: it is possible to assign each entry a unique monotonically increasing id? Does timeuuid and now() guarantee that inside a partition?

I want always to get data back exactly in the same order it was inserted, and wondering if I can achieve that without using a separate distributed service for generating ids.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra's `timeuuid` type have low enough probability for such tasks. I suggest to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612029/6570821) recent answer along with the  [Cassandra wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/TimeBaseUUIDNotes).